# Horizontal ListView in Column

Tags: flutter, dart

Iam trying to put a ListView with horizontal scrolldirection, into a Column.
I already tried to wrap the ListView into a Flexible and an Expanded Widget, nothing works.
I noticed several Threads but nothing helps:
[4 Horizontal Listviews in a Scrollable Column in FLutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64685849/4-horizontal-listviews-in-a-scrollable-column-in-flutter)
[Horizontal ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617126/horizontal-listview)
All the time the same exception occurs.

This is my build method:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.shade100),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return [
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 10.h,
                centerTitle: true,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(40))),
                backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar.createSettings(
                  child: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                    centerTitle: false,
                    title: Container(
                      width: 70.w,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/app_logo.png',
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                    ),
                    background: Container(
                      height: 10.h,
                      width: 100.w,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: kPrimaryColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(40)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  currentExtent: currentExtent,
                  maxExtent: maxExtent,
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: Consumer<HomeModel>(
            builder: (_, provider, a) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 100.w,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: Wrap(
                        spacing: 1.w,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 0.1.h,
                          ),
                          for (int i = 0;
                              i < provider.categoryChips.length;
                              i++)
                            _buildCategoryFilterChip(i, provider),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 0.1.h,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  /************************************************************
                   * This following ListView throws the exception. ************
                   ************************************************************/
                  ListView.separated(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 20,
                    separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Divider(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text('Item at $index'),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The following Error occurs:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#1d5ca relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1929 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column Column:file:///C:/Users/mm/StudioProjects/core/lib/ui/screens/_central/tabs/home/home_tab.dart:128:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1929:12)
#3      ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:57:18)
#4      RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)
#5      RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
#6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#7      RenderSliverFillRemainingWithScrollable.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fill.dart:92:14)
#8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#9      RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:510:13)
#10     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1580:12)
#11     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1489:20)
#12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#13     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#15     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#17     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#19     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#21     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#23     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#25     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#27     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#28     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
#29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#32     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#33     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1097:7)
#34     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#35     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:404:14)
#36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#40     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1388:11)
#41     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#42     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#43     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#44     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#45     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#46     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#48     RenderSliverFixedExtentBoxAdaptor.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fixed_extent_list.dart:240:19)
#49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#50     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:12)
#51     _RenderSliverFractionalPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver_fill.dart:167:11)
#52     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#53     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:510:13)
#54     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1580:12)
#55     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1489:20)
#56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#57     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#58     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#59     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#60     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#61     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#63     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#65     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#69     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#71     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#72     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
#73     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#74     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#75     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#76     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#77     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1097:7)
#78     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#79     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:404:14)
#80     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#81     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#82     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#83     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#84     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1388:11)
#85     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#86     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#87     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#88     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#89     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#90     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#91     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#92     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#93     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#94     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#95     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#96     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#97     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#98     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#99     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3422:13)
#100    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#101    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#102    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#103    _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:745:15)
#104    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#105    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#106    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#107    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#108    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#109    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#110    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#111    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#112    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#113    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#114    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#115    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#116    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#117    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#118    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#119    _RenderLayoutBuilder.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:365:14)
#120    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#121    _RenderLayoutBuilder.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:365:14)
#122    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#123    RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:165:14)
#124    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1713:7)
#125    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:885:18)
#126    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:453:19)
#127    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#128    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:319:5)
#129    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1143:15)
#130    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1080:9)
#131    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:863:7)
(elided 6 frames from class _AssertionError, class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFlex#7e932 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, -0.0)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, h=592.8)
...  size: MISSING
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
RenderObject: RenderFlex#7e932 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, -0.0)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, h=592.8)
  size: MISSING
  direction: vertical
  mainAxisAlignment: start
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  verticalDirection: down
...  child 1: RenderConstrainedBox#759ba relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    size: Size(392.7, 48.0)
...    additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    child: RenderRepaintBoundary#f3542 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...      layer: OffsetLayer#f93e7
...        engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#01287
...        handles: 2
...        offset: Offset(0.0, 140.3)
...      size: Size(392.7, 48.0)
...      metrics: 66.7% useful (2 bad vs 4 good)
...      diagnosis: this is a useful repaint boundary and should be kept
...      child: RenderCustomPaint#a8458 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none> (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...        size: Size(392.7, 48.0)
...        child: RenderRepaintBoundary#adb4d relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none> (can use size)
...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...          layer: OffsetLayer#3354f
...            engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#1d243
...            handles: 2
...            offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...          size: Size(392.7, 48.0)
...          metrics: 66.7% useful (2 bad vs 4 good)
...          diagnosis: this is a useful repaint boundary and should be kept
...  child 2: RenderRepaintBoundary#1d5ca relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    size: MISSING
...    usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
...    child: RenderCustomPaint#c682d relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...      size: MISSING
...      child: RenderRepaintBoundary#498de relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none> (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...        size: MISSING
...        usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
...        child: _RenderScrollSemantics#697ae relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...          parentData: <none> (can use size)
...          constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...          semantic boundary
...          size: MISSING
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#1d5ca relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1929 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column Column:file:///C:/Users/mm/StudioProjects/core/lib/ui/screens/_central/tabs/home/home_tab.dart:128:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1929:12)
#3      RenderBox.paintBounds (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2567:41)
#4      PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:140:56)
#5      PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
#6      PaintingContext._compositeChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:206:7)
#7      PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:187:7)
#8      RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2794:15)
#9      RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1078:7)
#10     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2409:7)
#11     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#12     RenderSliverSingleBoxAdapter.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1779:15)
#13     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2409:7)
#14     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:189:13)
#15     RenderViewportBase._paintContents (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:660:17)
#16     PaintingContext.pushLayer (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:398:12)
#17     PaintingContext.pushClipRect (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:454:7)
#18     RenderViewportBase.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:635:38)
#19     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2409:7)
#20     PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:141:11)
#21     PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:100:5)
#22     PipelineOwner.flushPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:979:29)
#23     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:455:19)
#24     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#25     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:319:5)
#26     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1143:15)
#27     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1080:9)
#28     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:863:7)
(elided 6 frames from class _AssertionError, class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFlex#7e932
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, -0.0)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, h=592.8)
...  size: MISSING
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: start
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
RenderObject: RenderFlex#7e932
  needs compositing
  parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, -0.0)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, h=592.8)
  size: MISSING
  direction: vertical
  mainAxisAlignment: start
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  verticalDirection: down
...  child 1: RenderConstrainedBox#759ba relayoutBoundary=up1
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    size: Size(392.7, 48.0)
...    additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    child: RenderRepaintBoundary#f3542 relayoutBoundary=up2
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...      layer: OffsetLayer#f93e7
...        engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#01287
...        handles: 2
...        offset: Offset(0.0, 140.3)
...      size: Size(392.7, 48.0)
...      metrics: 75.0% useful (2 bad vs 6 good)
...      diagnosis: this is a useful repaint boundary and should be kept
...      child: RenderCustomPaint#a8458 relayoutBoundary=up3
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none> (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...        size: Size(392.7, 48.0)
...        child: RenderRepaintBoundary#adb4d relayoutBoundary=up4
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none> (can use size)
...          constraints: BoxConstraints(w=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...          layer: OffsetLayer#3354f
...            engine layer: OffsetEngineLayer#1d243
...            handles: 2
...            offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...          size: Size(392.7, 48.0)
...          metrics: 75.0% useful (2 bad vs 6 good)
...          diagnosis: this is a useful repaint boundary and should be kept
...  child 2: RenderRepaintBoundary#1d5ca relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
...    needs compositing
...    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
...    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...    layer: OffsetLayer#33ab1 DETACHED
...      handles: 1
...      offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    size: MISSING
...    metrics: 0.0% useful (1 bad vs 0 good)
...    diagnosis: insufficient data to draw conclusion (less than five repaints)
...    child: RenderCustomPaint#c682d relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
...      needs compositing
...      parentData: <none> (can use size)
...      constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...      size: MISSING
...      child: RenderRepaintBoundary#498de relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
...        needs compositing
...        parentData: <none> (can use size)
...        constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...        size: MISSING
...        usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
...        child: _RenderScrollSemantics#697ae relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
...          needs compositing
...          parentData: <none> (can use size)
...          constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...          semantic boundary
...          size: MISSING
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: You need to give specific height to the listview.seprated

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap your ListView.separated with Sizedbox or Container and provide specific height. Any things in flutter which scrollDirection is horizontal it required height.

```
SizedBox(
         height: 50,
         child: ListView.separated(
         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
         shrinkWrap: true,
         itemCount: 20,
         separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Divider(),
         itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item at $index'),
                 );
                },
               ),
             ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code for ListView in Column
works for me now checked

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: [
                Text("sdf"),
                Text("sdf"),
                Text("sdf"),


              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],


      )

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and came to know that this scenario will not be possible until you give some fixed height to LIstView.builder(), As both column and ListView with horizontal direction, will take up all possible height.

The solution I came up with is, to create our own ListView.builder.

Just put all your widgets inside Row and Wrap it with SingleChildScrollView With a horizontal scroll direction.
Here

```
SingleChildScrollView(
     scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
             children: [
             for (var i = 0;i < 20;i++)
                  ListTile(title: Text('Item at $i')
                  ],
          ),
    ),
```

Comment: It works. However, it does not optimize memory consumption like the ListView widget, because all children are forced to be drawn inside the loop.